# Error in LESS file

Tags: css, less

I am getting this error while running the deploy command. What is the issue? Please help me. My code is

```
.fieldset {
                .field {
                    &:not(.choice) {
                        .label {
                            font-family: "Gotham-Medium", sans-serif;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 18px;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: code snippet]
[image: error(terminal)]

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

before line 2654 check all brackets

**Second solution**

&:not(.choice) issue is here please check this in inspect element.

```
.fieldset > .field:not(.choice) > .label
```

**I hope it's help.**